# How do I inflate a string JSON value to an object when parsing?

Tags: json, parsing, elm

I have a record that I parse from JSON:

```
import Json.Decode exposing (..)
import Json.Decode.Pipeline exposing (..)

type alias Article = {
    pubDate: String
}

articleDecoder : Decoder Article
articleDecoder =
    decode Article
        |> required "pubDate" string
```

Now if I want to use `Date` for `pubDate` instead of a raw string, how do I change the code to “inflate” the JSON value with `Date.fromString`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Terminology

There is no such term as *inflate* in Elm glossary.

You *decode* a JSON string or JavaScritpt Object.

There are no objects in Elm.

So you want to decode a string with formatted date into a data structure of [Date](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Date#Date) type.

## Implementation

As of today(`0.18.0`) [Date.fromString](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Date#fromString) from core is [proven to be unreliable.](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/issues/632)

You should use [Date.Extra.fromIsoString](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/elm-date-extra/2.0.2/Date-Extra#fromIsoString) from [justinmimbs/elm-date-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/elm-date-extra/2.0.2/) module for more reliable date parsing from ISO 8601.

I'm preserving namespaces for clarity.

```
dateDecoder : Decoder Date
dateDecoder =
    Json.Decode.string
        |> Json.Decode.andThen
            (\s ->
                case Date.Extra.fromIsoString s of
                    Err e ->
                        Json.Decode.fail e

                    Ok d ->
                        Json.Decode.succeed d
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this will work:

```
type alias Article = {
    pubDate: Date
}

articleDecoder : Decoder Article
articleDecoder =
    decode Article
        |> required "pubDate" pubDateDecoder

pubDateDecoder : Decoder Date.Date
pubDateDecoder =
    string |> andThen (\s ->
        case Date.fromString s of
            Err e -> fail e
            Ok d -> succeed d
        )
```